# codeigniter get_cookie does not return anything

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I have set a cookie in codeigniter. Checking with Firebug, I saw it is set. I used the following array to set it (on localhost)

```
$data['name'] = 'email';
$data['value'] = $guid;
$data['expire'] = (30*24*60*60);    
$data['secure'] = TRUE;
$data['domain'] = ".niazer.com";
set_cookie($data);
```

And then I used every possible function to get the cookie, but i was not successful.
As usual, I used this:

```
echo get_cookie("email"); // returned nothing
```

I changed it to this:

```
 echo get_cookie("email", false); // returned nothing
```

I then used input class:

```
echo $this->input->cookie('email'); // returned nothing.
```

In firebug, it shows my cookie like this: `niazer_email`

Therefore I added the prefix of 'niazer' for all of the above lines but still unsuccessful. Does anybody know why? It is worth mentioning that I also used `print_r` instead of `echo()` but still returned nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either take into account the default prefix (which is the site name), or clear this.

For example add the following line:

```
$data['prefix'] = '';
```

So:

```
$data['name'] = 'email';
$data['value'] = $guid;
$data['expire'] = (30*24*60*60);    
$data['secure'] = TRUE;
$data['domain'] = ".niazer.com";
$data['prefix'] = '';
set_cookie($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html). You can set the cookie like this

```
$cookie = array(
                    'name'   => 'my_cookie',
                    'value'  => '1200',
                    'expire' => '2592000', //30 days = 2592000 seconds
                    'secure' => TRUE
                );

$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

And can later on get it like this

```
echo $this->input->cookie('name'); //will echo 'my_cookie'
echo $this->input->cookie('value'); //will echo '1200'
```

Comment: `'secure' => TRUE` is provided for HTTPS requests, it won't work properly on HTTP.

Comment: OP has the `secure` option in his question. Otherwise he can remove it if he has to

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answer solved my problem. But I got it to work. How?

Since I was in a localhost, I set the `$cookie['path'] = "/"` and then set the `$cookie['SECURE'] = false` and this made my cookie working.